# How to call dll build from C# in vb6?

Tags: c#, vb6

I am a new programmer with VB6.
I want to use dll which i build in c# use in vb6.
What I used to try:
1. Create project in VS 2015 (New Project --> Class Library)

Here is the coding of my c# dll:

```
public class Class1
{
    public decimal Sum(decimal a, decimal b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

2. Than after i build completed, i copy c# dll into my window xp/system32
3. Open VB6 program --> Create project (Standard Exe)--> Project-->Reference-->Browse --> Alert error Message (Can't add a reference to the specified file)

I used to register this dll with command "regsvr32 dllname.dll" but it still not work.

Comment: `into my window xp/system32` i am afraid to even look at this post in the case you are infecting me with a virus

Comment: VB6 can only use 32 bit dlls. Although it can use 64 bit exes.

Comment: Have you searched on this site before posting your question? Or google? This is a widely documented area.

Comment: Thank you for much for help me! Have nice Day

Answer (score 3):

**C#** creates *.Net assemblies*, **Vb6** only knows about *COM libraries*

You will have to learn how to turn your **C# Assembly** in to a **COM library**

---

In short, to create a *COM Library* with a C# class project.

- The class should have an interface for the properties/methods and an interface for the events.
- Assign GUID attributes to the class and interfaces.

And then

```
In Project Properties > Application tab > Assembly Information button > check "Make assembly COM-Visible".
```

Also

```
In Project Properties > Build tab > Set "Platform target" to x86.
```

This makes all public methods in the class COM visible.

**Additional Info**

[Example COM Class (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/example-com-class)

Comment: Oh... right.. VB6! Wow. Yeah, apples and oranges...

Comment: Thank you for much for help me! Have nice Day